# Page transition on form button?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, transition

I'm trying this on my site

http://www.fasw.ws/demos/transitions1/slide1.html

everything is working good but not when i add data-ftrans="slide" to a form button.

example:

```
<form action"http://google.com"> <button data-ftrans="slide" type="submit" style="height:50px; font-size:20px;">Submit</button>
```

What does i need to change to get this working ?

Comment: We probably need more contextual code. Also, `<form action"http://google.com">` is malformed

Comment: google.com is used as example.

http://www.fasw.ws/demos/transitions1/js/fasw.transitions.min.js this is the js code.

Comment: And this <script type="text/javascript">
(function inittrans() 
{
 var params = //All params are optional, you can just assign {} 
  { 
   "navB" : "slide reverse", //Effect for navigation button, leave it empty to disable it
   "but" : true,    //Flag to enable transitions on button, false by default
   "cBa" : onTransitionFinished // function() { alert("Done!"); } //callback function
  };
 new ft(params);
})();

function onTransitionFinished()
{
 //Do anything you want 
}

</script>

Comment: What I'm saying is, the form tag you posted is malformed, specifically, missing the `=`.

Comment: Oh i'm sorry :) <form action="http://" id="search" name="search" method="post"> this is my form

Answer (score 0):

I think you must change your button to a depend on the context.
And must have 2 attribute 'href' and 'data-ftrans'. It'll run function slideTo(href, effect, pushstate) in the context.

- href: one html page
- data-ftrans: transition type

Maybe, you want to submit then change to another page (but not submit page)

```
     <form action="your server script" method="post">
    <button click="ajax_submit"></button>
     <a href="next page link" data-ftrans="type of transition" style="visibility:false">Hide</a>
   </form>

   <script>
   function ajax_submit(){
    //do some ajax code


    //when success
    //a.click();
 }
    </script>
```

Comment: What do you mean by change your button to a depend on the context? I have tried to add "href" in the button but then it doesnt take the POST parameters.

Comment: Do submit form via javascript when click to button.

Comment: Do you have a example of the javascript ?

Comment: document.getElementById("Form").submit();

Comment: i have tried this:         <button class="button" data-ftrans="slide" href="#" onclick="document.getElementById('search').submit();" style="height:50px; font-size:20px;">Submit</button>
 but the slide is still not working.